# undefined every time I want to get a guild by ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Every time I try to understand which guild appears under a certain ID by this code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = "!";

//guild
const cacheGuild = client.guilds.cache.get("686166514478612559");
```

I get undefined and I can't understand at all what could be the reason. Thanks!

Comment: How do you check it/use it?

Comment: So far only `console.log(cacheGuild);`

Comment: I don't see that in your code. Maybe you have wrong scope, maybe you have async function and try to return from, maybe _aliens_

Comment: Hi SHUSTRIK, could you share a bit more information about it, for example the context in which it is being used.
Maybe a silly question, but what does `cache.get` return if no matching guild is found ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client.guild.cache.get` is not a function.

As well as this, using the correct syntax, `console.log` would only log a `guildObject`.

In summary:

```js
const cacheGuild = client.guilds.fetch("686166514478612559");

console.log(cacheGuild.name); //since it is an object
```

As per the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager).